# Extracting metrics using the lidR::polygon_metrics function

Tags: r, lidr

I would like to extract a set of (x, y, z) based metrics from a lidar point cloud using the R lidR package. These metrics should be extracted for each field plot, the locations of which are in a shapefile. Each plot is represented by a 15m circular feature, in the shapefile.

I wrote the following code and it executes without any error messages. However, I am unsure if I am using the "~" based notation correctly. So, can you check if it is okay?

```
require(lidR)
require(sf)

myMetrics <- function(x, y, z, Intensity, ReturnNumber, Classification, dz)
{
  # ms1: metric set 1
  ms1 <- stdmetrics_z(z)
  ms2 <- stdmetrics_ctrl(x, y, z)
  ms3 <- stdshapemetrics(x, y, z)
  return (c(ms1, ms2, ms3))
}

# fieldPlots: Shapefile containing the location of the (15m size/circular) field plots.
fieldPlots <- st_read("plots.shp")
lasData <- lidR::readLAS("ALS_data.las")

d <- polygon_metrics(lasData, func = ~myMetrics(X, Y, Z, Intensity, ReturnNumber, Classification, dz=1), fieldPlots)
```

Can you also provide more information about how the code line with the polygon_metrics function call works? That is, how do the variables X, Y, Z etc get their values?

Comment: This looks correct. But there is a function `plot_metrics` more optimized for your specific case.

Comment: Thanks @JRR. Yes, I realize now that plot_metrics would have been better.